# Django tables 2: error django.template.context_processors.request

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I installed the module tables 2 and i have the next problem:

> Exception Value:   Tag {% querystring %} requires
>   django.template.context_processors.request to be in the template
>   configuration in settings.TEMPLATES[]OPTIONS.context_processors) in
>   order for the included template tags to function correctly.

My code is:

Settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR + '/llamadas/plantillas')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        llamadas = CallEntry.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('inicio.html', {'llamadas': llamadas})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/')
```

Inicio.html

```html
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% render_table llamadas %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `render_to_response` shortcut is not recommended any more.

Use the `render` shortcut instead, so that the context processors are used.

```
return render(request, 'inicio.html', {'llamadas': llamadas})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem is fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 context_processors.request in your settings:

**'django.core.context_processors.request',**

**'django.template.context_processors.request',**

maybe only one is necessary...

In onae of my projects I use only: **'django.core.context_processors.request'**, but the variable in the template, your **llamadas**, is an objet of type TableReport.

Comment: This won't fix the problem, but good spot! Since Django 1.8 it should be `'django.template.context_processors.request'`. The other one can be removed.