# django_tables2 gives Tag {% querystring %} error although it is included in settings.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-tables2, django-2.0

I have this very simple django_tables2 setup that gives this error and I don't understand why (http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html#list-of-dicts):

Error:

```
Tag {% querystring %} requires django.template.context_processors.request to be in the template configuration in settings.TEMPLATES[]OPTIONS.context_processors) in order for the included template tags to function correctly.
```

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request', # <-- included
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
```

views.py:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class RenderView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "test.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RenderView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data = [
            {'name': 'Bradley'},
            {'name': 'Stevie'},
        ]

        table = NameTable(data)

        context["table"] = table

        return context

class NameTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column()
```

test.html:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table table %}
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', RenderView.as_view(), name='test'),
]
```

Apparently there is no request property:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    print(self.request)
```

gives `'RenderView' object has no attribute 'request'`

django 2.0.2, python 3.6

Comment: Make sure you have shown your actual view, or even better, a simpler view that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair that's the whole view, I added the imports now. deleted everything unrelated to the table

Comment: @Alasdair i was wondering if there might be related to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592783/django-template-context-processors-request-issue-with-django-tables2-and-djang , that `request ` should be used, but unsure how to pass the request using get_context_data method, as this is the template across all site and don't want to change to render(request, ...)

Comment: In that question, they had to pass the request manually because they were using `template.render()` or `render_to_string`. In your case, the `TemplateView` should run the context processors and include the `request` in the template context. I can't see why you would get your error for the view you have shown. The `__init__` method is odd (I would remove it and simply write `template_name=test.html`), but I don't think that's what's causing the issue. If that's your real view, what is `context["data"] =  "data"` for?

Comment: @Alasdair it was just to suggest that I have more things going on. I removed the context["data"] and everything else from the view... but still the same error. maybe because django2? can't see that they explicitly support django 2.

Comment: I'd be surprised if it was a Django 2.0 issue. I can't see any issues with your current view, and I'm not in a position to test it, so I don't have any other suggestions. Note that overriding `__init__` in class based views is unusual, usually you'd override other methods instead.

Comment: @Alasdair found what the issue was. I was including `{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table table %}` inside another template tag and then inside the template through that tag. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So when you said that your simplified view gave the same error, you didn't actually try running the simplified view and template from your question? :(

Comment: @Alasdair I did run it, but forgot that test.html included in another tag and  that was what gave the error. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your load tags in your template to:

```
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% render_table table %}
```